# Have been and Had been, excluding present perfect continuous and past perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-participles

**We use the verb had and the past participle for the past perfect and The past perfect continuous is formed with had been and the -ing form of the verb:**

> 1. When Mel died he and Jenifer had been married for nearly thirty years.
> 2. He didn’t want to move. He had lived in Seattle  all her life.

In sentence 1, had+married, **past participle for marry**, why is *been* here and what does it mean by placing here?

In sentence 2, had+lived **past participle** : why is *been* not used here?

I mean to ask, why do we sometimes use *had been* and *have been*  **excluding the past perfect and present perfect continuous sentences** in a sentence, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

*Married* is the past participle of *marry*; but in sentence 1 it is actually employed not as a verb but as an adjective, the predicative complement of *BE*.

> They had been married for thirty years *has the same structure as*
>   They had been happy for thirty years.

The verb group in both of these sentences is *had been*: *had* + the pa·ppl of *BE*.

However, you will also find constructions in the form *had been VERB<sup>pa·ppl</sup>* where *VERB* really is a verb; the construction is the past perfect passive:

> John was depressed because he ***had been fired***.

This uses the pa·ppl of *BE* as the complement of the perfect auxiliary *HAVE*, and the pa·ppl of *fire* as the complement of the passive auxiliary *BE*.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I have a doubt.                                              He didn’t want to move. He had lived in Seattle all his life.                         Can we  place been in between  had and lived.                                    Do we use Have/has+been or Had+been in only passive sentence or other types of sentences also?     What is the difference between had fired and had been fired.

Comment: @asr09 Apparently you have not yet learned about the ***passive*** voice, in which an object of an active transitive verb is cast as the subject of a the same verb in the passive. The passive is formed with a form of *BE* + the pa·ppl of the verb. For instance: in simple present, an active sentence like *John fires George* becomes passive *George is fired (by John)*. In past perfect *John had fired George* becomes *George had been fired (by John)*.